# Can't get senders email address from read receipts

Tags: powershell, outlook

I am using the code posted on here to try and retrieve the senders email address form read receipts in PowerShell. For some emails this works OK but for others it does not work.

In Outlook I can clearly see who it's from, but PowerShell returns a blank cell.

Any help please?

```
function Get-OutlookInBox {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | Out-Null
    $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    $folder = $NameSpace.pickfolder()
    $Folder.Items | Get-Member
    $Folder.Items |
        Select-Object Subject, SenderName, SenderEmailAddress, CreationTime,
            ReceivedTime, Final-recipient, UserProperties, ItemProperties,
            MAPIOBJECT, ReceivedByName, Recipents, Sender, SentOn,
            SentOnBehalfOfName |
        Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation xxx\Trial.csv
}
```

Comment: You mean, it does not work in other computers? Is the correct version of PowerShell installed there? Please [edit]() your question and provide more details on this error.

Comment: At first glance i see a typo in your code. `Recipents` should be `Recipients`. Next you also state `MAPIOBJECT` in your Select-Object staement, but that property is deprecated. Are you sure all items in the folder are **MailItem** objects and the folder does not contain any **PostItem** objects? They have different properties. For MailItems look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem_properties.aspx and for PostItem objects see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.postitem_properties(v=exchg.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that specified exist and can't be retrieved for a particular object. For example, I have noticed the `Final-recipient` which doesn't have any corresponding property in the OOM.

Note, you need to iterate over all items in the folder and deal with mail items only because other Outlook items may not have properties specified to export. So, you may check the `Class` property before doing anything.

A yet better solution is to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to get items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)